# my input is a string consisting of numbers seperated by space like 10 20 200 120 50 i need to print largest number in the array

Tags: c

Can any one help me please. I need to perform any operation on such type of input format:

The input is a string consisting of numbers separated by space like
  10 20 200 120 50 
 I need to print largest number in the array.
I am unable perform operations since in strings s[3] means it takes fourth value
that is 2 but how to separate 10 and 20 and then compare or perform some arithmetic operation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Answer (score -1):

Here, What you can do is , you can separate the string using `' '` (Space),
Store it somewhere, convert it to integer using the `atoi()` function and then compare.